# Exception found updated poll watermark: Variable is not serializable

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am geting the following exception in Mule Poll/Watermark:

> Exception found updating watermark java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Value retrieved from event for variable carimboTempo is not
>   serializable and hence cant be saved to the object store

Partial XML configuration:

```
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="${crm.db.host}" port="${crm.db.port}" user="${crm.db.user}" password="${crm.db.password}" database="${crm.db.instance}" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
<flow name="levius-contatoFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10000"/>
        <watermark variable="carimboTempo" default-expression="2016-03-24 00:00:00" update-expression="#[flowVars.date_modified]"/>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select 
ac.id,
c.first_name,
c.last_name,
greatest(ac.date_modified, c.date_modified) date_modified
from accounts_contacts ac
join contacts c on c.id = ac.contact_id
where greatest(ac.date_modified, c.date_modified) > #[carimboTempo]
order by greatest(ac.date_modified, c.date_modified)]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </poll>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <set-variable variableName="date_modified" value="#[payload.date_modified]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Why this exception occur? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: carimboTempo is also a flow variable. Should be #[flowVars.carimboTempo]

Comment: What's the type of `flowVars.date_modified`? I was expecting `java.sql.Date`, which is serializable, but the exception says otherwise.

Comment: `flowVars.date_modified` is a java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: Ralph, `update-expression` has  `flowVars.date_modified` and I set this variable with `payload.date_modified`. But even so, I did a test and let the empty the `update-expression` and I setted `carimboTempo` directly, but it did not work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error. Could you try this:

## [sessionVars.lastUpdated == null?lastModified:sessionVars.lastUpdated]

I think, the flow is trying to serialize null value.

Comment: I putted in update-expression the following and works: `#[if (flowVars.date_modified == null) { flowVars.carimboTempo; } else { flowVars.date_modified; }]`